# How to use XML string input in SP to delete rows based on two column values

Tags: xml, stored-procedures

I'm trying to delete multiple rows from a table using XML input.  Delete is based on two column values: OwnerKey and QuestionNumber.  (Neither column contains unique values.)

The only way I can figure to make this work is to build a temporary table that contains the XML input values (ie - the 2 columns) and then issue a DELETE based on a JOIN of the temporary table and the target table.  [I'm all ears if someone has a better approach.]

The problem that I'm running into now is that the CREATE PROC fails with an "Invalid Column name" message - pointing to "QuestionNumber" - the second attribute in the XML string.

If I explicitly list both columns in the SELECT INTO statement, I get a syntax error - so I used **SELECT ***.   This doesn't work either.

Can anyone give me an example of how to do this?

```
XML Input string (formatted here for readability):
-- <Answers>
--     <WebUser OwnerKey="104" QuestionNumber="1"/>
--     <WebUser OwnerKey="104" QuestionNumber="3"/>
-- </Answers>
```

SP:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE WebUserDeleteAnswer 
    @DeleteXMLString text
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @hDoc int
    EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT,
        @DeleteXMLString

    SELECT * INTO #temp     
--      OwnerKey                
--      INTO #temp      
    FROM OPENXML(@hdoc, 'Answers/WebUser', 2)

    DELETE FROM WebUser 
    WHERE ( WebUser.OwnerKey = OwnerKey 
        AND WebUser.wu_QuestionNumber = **QuestionNumber**)

    DROP TABLE #temp

    EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc

END
GO
```

---

Figured it out.  Needed to modify the SELECT and DELETE commands:

(Changed **#temp** to **XmlTable** for clarity)

```
    BEGIN 
    DECLARE @hDoc int
    EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT,
        @DeleteXMLString

    SELECT * INTO XmlTable  
    FROM OPENXML(@hdoc, 'Answers/WebUser', 2) 
    WITH (OwnerKey int '@OwnerKey',
          QuestionNumber int '@QuestionNumber') 


    DELETE WebUser
    FROM WebUser
        INNER JOIN XmlTable ON
        (XmlTable.OwnerKey = WebUser.OwnerKey)
        AND (XmlTable.QuestionNumber = WebUser.wu_QuestionNumber)

    EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
    DROP TABLE XmlTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  Needed to change the DELETE command:
        BEGIN 
        DECLARE @hDoc int
        EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT,
            @DeleteXMLString

```
    SELECT * INTO XmlTable  
    FROM OPENXML(@hdoc, 'Answers/WebUser', 2) 
    WITH (OwnerKey int '@OwnerKey',
          QuestionNumber int '@QuestionNumber') 


    DELETE WebUser
    FROM WebUser
        INNER JOIN XmlTable ON
        (XmlTable.OwnerKey = WebUser.OwnerKey)
        AND (XmlTable.QuestionNumber = WebUser.wu_QuestionNumber)

    EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
    DROP TABLE XmlTable
```